# Concurrent Modification Exception in Jasper Report

Tags: java, swing, jasper-reports

I am working on a Java swing based stand alone application, where I have to package my Jasper reports in the jar file. The reports uses sub-reports also.

When I run the reports in eclipse IDE, it works fine, means all report with or without sub-reports are running properly; but when I package them in the jar file, only the reports without sub-reports are working properly and the reports using the subreports are throwing below exception-

```
Exception in thread "Thread-7" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(Unknown Source)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.BaseFillHandle.notifyError(BaseFillHandle.java:210)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.BaseFillHandle$ReportFiller.run(BaseFillHandle.java:135)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The reports are structured in following directory hierarchy-

```html
+ main
|------+ reports
       |--------+ invoice
       |        |--------> invoice_master.jasper
       |        |--------> invoice_sub_report.jasper  
       |---------> end_of_the_day_report.jasper
```

What I mean is 'end_of_the_day_report.jasper' works fine in the jar package, but '/reports/invoice/invoice_master.jasper' do not, throwing above exception.

I have passed the 'SUBREPORT_DIR' parameter as '/reports/invoice/' for the 'invoice_master.jasper' report.

I am using 'jasperreports 5.6.0' library in my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found reason for above problem after a lot of test cases and references.

At first site the concurrent modification seems to be strange and seems to be due to concurrent modification of some collection. But in my case below strategy worked for me-

1. When the report is of single page it is fine to read it even inside the jar package. But for reports having multiple sub-reports
   will not work inside the jar package, because it is zipped. You have two solutions

   **a)** You are firm to put the jasper files inside the jar package, than read the post here -

Load all sub-reports using Input Stream in your Java Code, and pass them into the parameters map

In the iReport designer map those parameters with the sub-reports

```
JasperReport jasperReport = null;
JasperReport subReport = null;
String reportPath = "/reports/invoice/invoice_master.jasper";
String subReportPath = "/reports/invoice/invoice_sub_report.jasper";
try {
//load the the reports
jasperReport = (JasperReport)JRLoader.loadObject(getClass().getResource(reportPath));

subReport = (JasperReport)JRLoader.loadObject(getClass().getResource(subReportPath));

//pass the subReport object as a parameter to the jasperReport
Map<String, Object> reportParams = new HashMap<String, Object>();
params.put("SUB_JASPER", subReport);

//finally pass the parameter map to the report.
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, params, connectionOrOtherDataSource);
//... do something with jasperPrint
} catch (JRException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

In your Jasper file you should have -

i) Create a report parameter "SUB_JASPER" with Parameter Class set to `net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport`

ii) Click on the subreport, set the Expression Class property to `net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport` and Subreport Expression to the parameter "$P{SUB_JASPER}".

**b)** You are flexible to put the jasper reports outside of the jar package, then read below-

Put your all reports in reports directory or its sub-directory, where the jar file and reports directory are
        in same level.
        If your reports uses images than put them also at the reports directory level under images directory.
        So your directory structure will becomes now as-

```
    + myapp.jar
    + images
    |--------->image1.png
    + reports
    |--------+ invoice
    |        |--------> invoice_master.jasper
    |        |--------> invoice_sub_report.jasper  
    |--------> end_of_the_day_report.jasper
```

**Note:-** "*image1.png*" is the image used in jasper reports.
        When you run the jar file the directory that contains the jar file is automatically in the class-path, so the
        reports and images are also in search path list.
        
Hope this works for you too!!